# Apagar arquivo (foto) da pasta quando realizar update

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldade em um código. Estou criando um formulário com uma foto de perfil, porém quando fizer uma alteração da foto no EDITAR, gostaria que a foto fosse excluída da pasta das imagens. Hoje só consigo excluir e alterar a foto, mas a antiga permanece. O código abaixo é o que uso pra excluir um registro da minha lista:

```
public void apagar(UsuarioModel selcionado){
   if (selecionado != null){
      try{
          if (new UsuarioDao().apagar(selecionado)){
              lista.remove(selcionado);
              }

      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o caminho da imagem deva estar vinculada a um atributo da classe `UsuarioModel`, seguindo por essa suposição de maneira fácil e descomplicada utilize a classe `Files` do pacote `java.nio.file.Files` para isso;

> Método Estático -> Files.deleteIfExists(Path path)

```
public void apagar(UsuarioModel selcionado){
   if (selecionado != null){
      try{
          if (new UsuarioDao().apagar(selecionado)){
              Path path = Paths.get(selecionado.getCaminhoParaImagem()).normalize();
              // O método estático deleteIfExists retorna um booleano
              boolean removeu = Files.deleteIfExists(path)
          }    
      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem o caminho da imagem ou do arquivo é só fazer:

```
 File imagem = new File("path/da/imagem");
 imagem.delete();
```

.delete()  => retorno booleano.
Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa do caminho do arquivo antes de mais nada de uma olhada no código abaixo que vai ficar claro para vc

```
String fileName = "C:\images\olamundo.jpg";
removerArquivo(fileName);
public void removeArquivo (String fileName) 
{
    File file = new File(fileName);
    file.delete();
}
```

espero ter ajudado.